# how to concatenate an integer and a string from an array

Tags: c, arrays, concatenation, type-conversion

I have an array of integers and an array of chars.

```
int A[5] = {12, 23, 12, 32, 12};
char B[5] = {'a', 'e', 'd', 'y', 'i'};
```

I want to concatenate the two in order into a new array called

```
char P[5];
```

I want to output to be

```
p[5] =  {12a, 23e, 12d, 32y, 56i}
```

So far I tried using snprintf but it runs into segment fault and abort trap 6. Is there a simpler way to do this ?

Comment: 1) `[4]` --> `[5]` 2) `char P[4];` --> `char *P[5]; `

Comment: You need [5] in the array declarations for A, B and P, since each one will be storing five elements. snprintf is probably the simplest solution without using a non-standard library. Could your array sizing be the cause of your segfault?

Comment: @user234461 : not sure, could you write up a little function that could help me out please

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/7GmbnA)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY beautiful !!!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : perfecto !

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a `char` array storing values like `'12e'` at each index, you need a 2D-char array (which is an array of strings). You can use `sprintf` for data type conversion.

```
int A[5] = {12, 23, 12, 32, 12};
char B[5] = {'a', 'e', 'd', 'y', 'i'};
char P[5][15];
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    sprintf(P[i], "%d%c",A[i],B[i]);
    printf("%s ",P[i]);
}
```

output: `12a 23e 12d 32y 12i`

Comment: If you want to simplify, replace the first 4 lines in the for loop with sprintf(P[i],"%d%c",A[i], B[i]);

Comment: That's cool. Updated my answer accordingly. Thank you Justin.